# 0x8007054f an internal error occurred trying to create file

Tags: windows, macos, file-permissions, home-directory

In a scenario where a Windows domain controller was configured with Folder Redirection (for its domain users) to an existing set of folders on a Mac Server, that is/was being used by Mac domain users, a logged in Windows domain user receives the error message "**0x8007054f an internal error occurred trying to create file**" when trying to create a file in one of the redirected folders (eg. Desktop).

The Folder Redirection GPO was disabled, and the Windows domain user's local folders were restored, but the error still exists when the user tries to create a file in the Mac network folder (that was used in the redirection GPO).

**The user can write to the parent folder, write to a child folder within the problem folder, but not to the folder itself.**

This problem exists ONLY for a user that logged onto the Windows domain whilst the Folder Redirection GPO was active.  Other Windows domain users that did not have any redirection/sync settings applied yet can write to the folders without issue.

It seems the application of the policy to the users changed permissions on the Mac folders in some way, but I cannot determine how to fix it.

**Any suggestions?**

---

If you are unsure what I mean, visualise the following setup:

A Mac LDAP domain with Home folder synching (Desktop, Documents etc.) for two Mac OS X clients.  The home folders for each user live on \\macserver.domain.com.au\NetworkUsers\$UID. *$UID being the user name.*
These same two clients had boot-camp configured and Windows installed (as a trial Windows network environment).

A Windows 2008 R2 Server which is a DC for other Windows users of a different department is already configured on the network.  A user account for the boot-camp computers is created with the same username and password as they use on the LDAP Mac domain.
The Windows 7 clients are joined to a Windows domain (hosted by server2.domain.local) which has a Folder Redirection GPO configured.
The GPO says Desktop is to be on \\macserver.domain.com.au\NetworkUsers\%username%.
One of the boot-camp clients is booted and logged in, the other is not (yet).  The folder redirection looks like it has worked, but then it is discovered that the error message (above) appears whenever an attempt to write to a "synched" directory occurs.  The idea of using folder redirection to give these trial users access to their existing Mac data in "the equivalent location" is abandoned and the GPO is revoked.  Local directory access for clients is restored and a mapped network drive to their Mac home folder is setup instead.
The other boot-camp client is booted and logged in to the Windows domain.  Everything works OK. They can read AND write to the mapped drive and any directories within.   But, the original boot-camp client (that was affected by the GPO) cannot write to any of the folders used in the GPO.  Ie. they can write to \\macserver.domain.com.au\NetworkUsers\%username%, but not \\macserver.domain.com.au\NetworkUsers\%username%\Desktop.  But what is strange is that they CAN write to \\macserver.domain.com.au\NetworkUsers\%username%\Desktop\Other-folder without any error...